# Startx as non-root user via SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, non-root-user, file-descriptors

I have a remote VM running Ubuntu 1804 and would like to run VNC. I am using x11vnc, which requires an X server to be running. Currently, I'm connected through SSH.

The VM has an Nvidia card, and after generating the xorg.conf with nvidia-xconfig, I can start an X session using startx, but only as root. Any subsequent connection via VNC is with root, which I want to avoid.

The Device section in xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Tesla K80"
    BusID          "0:30:0"
EndSection
```

When trying to launch startx as a non-root user, I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
```

If I change the /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config to allow anybody to startx, I get the following:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

I've been reading that connecting via SSH doesn't mean that you're connected to a text console, which you need to run startx. Trying to change to a text console with chvt fails doesn't change anything.

Is there anyway that I can launch X via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554603/118662) is a solution based on `systemd-run`, it tricks `startx` into thinking that it has been run from a virtual terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a login manager (say, `lightdm`) and configure autologin. Even run `x11vnc` at the start of the user's sesion.

Alternatively you can run `vncserver` as the user and then connect directly to it, via ssh forwarding:

```
ssh -L5904:localhost:5905 user@example.com
vncserver :5 # only if the server has not been started
```

and then, on the client you can run:

```
xvncviewer localhost:4
```

Comment: I previously tried doing this and just tried again. If I do this, then X is started by vncserver. If this happens then I don't have the hardware acceleration with the GPU (checked with glxinfo). This is why I think I have to start X separately.

Comment: Ok, you need hardware acceleration. Does the autologin work for you? I don't see how you profit from acceleration though once you pipe your session through x11vnc though. You are going to be running `VNC` on top of X in that case.

Comment: I'll be trying soon. I need hardware acceleration because I'm rendering with Blender and it requires OpenGL through X (no support for EGL) for the Eevee renderer.

Comment: Lightdm doesn't work as Xorg is also launched by root. I tried xhost + for the root X display and then x11vnc -users +ubuntu but that still is only in root mode.

Comment: With lightdm you would not be doing `startx`, the X server would be brought up by lightdm itself (that's how normal desktops work). Then, the autologin feature will land you into the user you want to start the session as.